# Mongoid create vs collection.insert

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I'm not sure how to put this.  Well, recently I worked on a rails project with mongoid, and I had the task of inserting multiple records in Mongodb.

Say insert multiple records of PartPriceRecord in the database.  After googling this I came across the **collection.insert** commands:

> PartPriceRecord.collection.insert(multiple_part_price_records)

But on inserting large number of records, MongoDb always seemed to prompt me with error message:

**Exceded maximum insert size of 16,000,000 bytes**

Googling around I found that the the upper limit for MongoDb for a single document, but surprisingly when I changed my above query to this:

```
multiple_part_price_records.each do|mppr|
  PartPriceRecord.create(mppr)
end
```

the above errors do not seem to appear any more.

Can anyone explain in depth under the hood what is exactly is the difference between the two?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum size for a single, bulk insert is 16M bytes. That's what you're trying to do in your first example.

In your second example, you're inserting each document individually. Therefore, each insert is under the max limit for an insert.

Comment: Does that mean Create command ,create create a separate document everytime did not knew that

Comment: Then how do achieve mass insert like above without resulting in 16M bytes errors from mongodb

Comment: To do the massive insert, you'll need to reduce the number of documents you're inserting.

Comment: Sure wasn't there any other way

Answer (score 3):

@Kyle explained the difference in his answer quite succinctly (+1'd), but as for a solution to your problem you may want to look at doing batch inserts:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 200
multiple_part_price_records.each_slice(BATCH_SIZE) do |batch|
    PartPriceRecord.collection.insert(batch)
end
```

This will slice the records into batches of 200 (or whatever size is best for your situation) and insert them within that limit. This will be a **lot** faster than running save on each one individually which would be sending far more requests to the database.

A few quick things to note about collection.insert:

- It does **not** run validations on your models prior to insertion, you may want to check this prior to insert
- It is required to be in a document format unlike save which requires it be a model. You can easily convert to a document by calling `as_document` on the model.

Comment: I think that the correct function is `as_document`. At least `to_document` gave me an `undefined method` error. Thanks.